# Speed no improvement in Tensorrt

Tags: tensorflow, tensorrt

I have Openpose's [Tensorflow graph](https://www.dropbox.com/s/he172yau97rcrop/graph_opt.pb?dl=0).

The graph is converted to uff format using convert-to-uff command.

The output is

```
NOTE: UFF has been tested with TensorFlow 1.12.0. Other versions are not guaranteed to work
UFF Version 0.6.3
=== Automatically deduced input nodes ===
[name: "image"
op: "Placeholder"
attr {
  key: "dtype"
  value {
    type: DT_FLOAT
  }
}
attr {
  key: "shape"
  value {
    shape {
      dim {
        size: -1
      }
      dim {
        size: -1
      }
      dim {
        size: -1
      }
      dim {
        size: 3
      }
    }
  }
}
]
=========================================

=== Automatically deduced output nodes ===
[name: "Openpose/concat_stage7"
op: "ConcatV2"
input: "Mconv7_stage6_L2/BiasAdd"
input: "Mconv7_stage6_L1/BiasAdd"
input: "Openpose/concat_stage7/axis"
attr {
  key: "N"
  value {
    i: 2
  }
}
attr {
  key: "T"
  value {
    type: DT_FLOAT
  }
}
attr {
  key: "Tidx"
  value {
    type: DT_INT32
  }
}
]
==========================================

Using output node Openpose/concat_stage7
Converting to UFF graph
No. nodes: 463
UFF Output written to cmu/cmu_openpose.uff
```

How do I know the conversion is correct and all nodes are converted?

The problem is speed has no improvement in running Tensorrt engine/

I used Tensorrt 5.1.5 GA.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

I did more reading and understanding on TensorRT.
For those who has same issue, let me describe what I understood. Please comment, if my understanding is wrong.

My uff conversion is fine. No error. I checked at the graph at Tensorboard and all input/outputs are fine.

My GPU is Quadro P4000. That graphic card support precision FP32 only.

TensorRT does not have faster processing speed than running Tensorflow on GPU using FP32 unless graphsurgeon modifies the graph.

The advantage is converting the TensorRT engine to FP16 or INT8 format. Then can see the advantages of using TensorRT.

In FP32 format, there is no advantage of using TensorRT over Tensorflow running on GPU.

Comment: `In FP32 format, there is no advantage of using TensorRT over Tensorflow running on GPU.` This is not true at all! Check the answers from above.

Answer (score 1):

> TensorRT optimizes the network by combining layers and optimizing
>   kernel selection for improved latency, throughput, power efficiency
>   and memory consumption. If the application specifies, it will
>   additionally optimize the network to run in lower precision, further
>   increasing performance and reducing memory requirements.

As stated in *TensorRT Developer Guide*, it improves DL models not only by *running in lower precision*, but by *combining layers and optimizing kernel selection* also.

If your GPU doesn't have support for mixed-precision this doesn't means that TensorRT is not useful. TensorRT will do layer fusion and will run various kernels in order to pick the most efficient ones.

There could be other reasons if you don't see any improvement. Maybe the way you are using the *cmu/cmu_openpose.uff* engine.

Answer (score 1):

Your understanding of tensorRt is incorrect.
The major reason that tensorRt inference may be faster than tensorflow inference comes from:

1. Aggressively fusing several layer kernels into one single kernel. i.e., https://miro.medium.com/max/1155/0*7WA6t51EZ46355m6.
2. Auto tuning and selecting the fastest kernel implementation for your input sizes.
3. Reduced precision inference.

If your network has a lot of memory heavy operations: tf.slice, tf.split, tf.concat, or a lot of elementwise operations (e.g, `tf.exp(tf.exp( a + b - c)` ), there is little that can be done by tensorRt since the fused kernel is not implemented (cannot fuse two consecutive exp ops) or there is little to optimize for memory operations.

That said, it also depends on the input size into your model. 
Launching a cuda kernel would incur overhead (say 0.1 ms). If the input size is 10x10 instead of 1000x1000, then computation time is trivial compared to kernel launch time. You would not see a lot of gains from using tensorRt if the amount of required computation is small.

I converted your model and run inference on it with TensoRt5.1.5 on a TitanXp (FP32). Here is what i got:

```
B=1 TensorRT avg per image 0.4569686s over 1000 iter.
B=1 Tensorflow avg per image 0.5385810s over 1000 iter.
```

Image size is 1x3x1200x1920 (batch x channels x height x width).